# Eriksson's thesis "Strongly convergent games and Coxeter groups"

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, coxeter-groups

The [diamond lemma](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/algebra/diamond-talk.pdf) has recently come up in my teaching, and as always I've been looking for nice and simple applications. This has reminded me of the thesis

Kimmo Eriksson, *Strongly convergent games and Coxeter groups*, KTH Stockholm 1993,

which I have never been able to locate despite the existence of [a ProQuest page](https://www.proquest.com/docview/304095210) and many (Google Scholar says 60) citations in the literature.

Does anyone have a scan of this thesis? (I am aware of several papers by Eriksson, but I'm not sure how much of the thesis they cover.)

Comment: Is there a particular result you're interested in that you believe is contained in this thesis?

Comment: @SamHopkins: I'm hoping for more elementary applications to use in my lecture :)

Comment: Have you tried writing to [Kimmo](https://www.iffs.se/en/research/researchers/kimmo-eriksson-1/)? I'm sure that if anyone has a copy, it's him. (As an aside, Kimmo's father Henrik did a PhD in 1994, also at KTH and on a similar topic, and this thesis is available [here](https://www.csc.kth.se/~viggo/henrik/he/thesis.pdf)).

Comment: Also, if you want nice and simple applications of the diamond lemma, it is used all the time in string rewriting systems and combinatorial (semi)group theory. The easiest application is to show that the bicyclic monoid has decidable word problem; or that free groups are well-defined as the group of all freely reduced words with multiplication given by concatenation, followed by reducing.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: Thanks for the suggestions! I have the bicyclic monoid in my plan (actually in a slightly stronger form, saying that parenthesis matching is confluent even if you don't remove the matched parenthesis but merely "freeze" them; this is how it is used all over combinatorics). For some reason, I had forgotten about the free group. I probably have enough easy examples now, though I sure wouldn't mind more.

Comment: An application of the diamond lemma to enumeration can be found in the proof of Theorem 4.4 in my paper with Ji Li, Enumeration of point-determining graphs, J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 118 (2011), 591–612, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2010.03.009.

Comment: @IraGessel: Nice! One of my examples (perhaps the simplest) is the uniqueness of the $k$-core of a graph (i.e., if you successively delete vertices of degree $\leq k$, the result at the end will not depend on your choices). This looks similar but more advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thesis can now be found at https://archive.org/details/eriksson-strongly-convergent-games-thesis .

Thanks to Kimmo Eriksson for sending me a hard copy and allowing it to be shared!